# ASP Dictionary in array memory handling

Tags: arrays, memory-leaks, asp-classic, dictionary

I have a piece of code that takes several rows from a database and creates a dictionary object which I push into an array.

```
do while index < rs.RecordCount or (not rs.EOF)
  set dict = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

  for each x in rs.fields
    temp = x.value
    dict.add lcase(x.name), temp
  next

  set records(index) = dict

  index = index + 1
  rs.moveNext
  set dict = nothing
loop
```

I usually call set object = nothing when done with a dictionary but do I have to go through the whole array here (records) and set each index to "nothing"?

I am wondering because of memory management and unsure how IIS and ASP handles it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you don't.

The script engine will free those variables as soon as they go out of scope.

The whole 'set objects to nothing' practice is advocated on an implicit 'just in case' thinking by people who haven't bothered to check the facts.

Drop the practice. And read [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2004/04/28/122259.aspx).